# Retrieve first word in list index python

Tags: python, list

I want to know how to retrieve the first word at list index.

For example, if the list is:

```
['hello world', 'how are you']
```

Is there a way to get `x = "hello how"`?

Here is what I've tried so far (`newfriend` is the list):

```
x=""

for values in newfriend:
        values = values.split()
        values = ''.join(values.split(' ', 1)[0])
        x+=" ".join(values)

x+="\n"
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple generator expression would do, I guess, e.g.

```
>>> l = ["hello world", "how are you"]
>>> ' '.join(x.split()[0] for x in l)
'hello how'
```

Comment: Not list inside string ! List inside List element string ! Vote down -1

Comment: what is the issue with this code ? Sorry i'm just starting Python

Comment: @zezollo: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Let me explain: OP's *list* was `{[hello world], [how are you]}`. But that isn't valid Python code and doesn't make any sense. However, from the code OP already wrote, I think he means `['hello world', 'how are you']` so I edited the question. And I also hope that dsgdfg can removes his downvote.

Comment: @DonkeyKong There was only a very brief moment during which my English text still said 'list comprehension' but the code already used a generator expression. Maybe that's when you looked at it. I fixed it a couple of seconds later.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe No sorry, that was in response to DougR's now deleted comment, I saw that you edited your original answer after my original comment :) also nice answer, +1

Comment: @KevinGuan, thanks for the explanation! I hadn't considered the comment could have been caused by such a situation. Also hope dsgdfg can remove his|her downvote now this is cleared.

Comment: Nope ! Vote up now !

Answer (score 1):

You're not far off.  Here is how I would do it.

```
# Python 3
newfriend = ['hello world', 'how are you']
x = []  # Create x as an empty list, rather than an empty string.
for v in newfriend:
    x.append(v.split(' ')[0])  # Append first word of each phrase to the list.

y = ' '.join(x)  # Join the list.
print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
#where l =["Hello world","hi world"]
g=[]
for i in range(l):
   x=re.findall(r'\w+',l[i])
   g.append(x)
print(g[0][0]+g[1][0])
```